# How to set Codeigniter based url in Cron job?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I am using Codeigniter for my website. I have to use a Cron job to run one of the controller functions. 
I used all these options in a Cron job but all not working.

```
0 * * * * php /home/username/public_html/ /controller/method

0 * * * * php /home/username/public_html/ controller/method

0 * * * * php /home/username/public_html/ controller method

0 * * * * php /home/username/public_html/index.php /controller/method

0 * * * * php /home/username/public_html/index.php controller/method

0 * * * * php /home/username/public_html/index.php controller method
```

```sh
wget -O /dev/null https://websiteurl/url >/dev/null   {websiteurl = website url} {url = route url}
```

if I place any PHP file in the main directory then it works fine. but not working for Codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cron.php file in the main directory

```
<?php
$argc = $_SERVER['argc'];
$argv = $_SERVER['argv'];
 
// INTERPRETING INPUT
if ($argc > 1 && isset($argv[1])) {
    $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']   = $argv[1];
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $argv[1];
} else {
    $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']   = '/crons/index';
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/crons/index';
}
 
set_time_limit(0);
 
require_once('index.php');
?>
```

I have used below cron

```
30 * * * * php /var/www/html/cron.php /controller/method
```

Works for me

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried another way. created a file in the main directory. and call Codeigniter full URL through curl and this worked for me

Comment: but if you add a new crontab to call other controllers should you create a new file too?

Answer (score 0):

I tried different options but unable to figure out the problem. But the below method solved my problem.

Created a file in the main directory. in this file, I used curl to call CodeIgniter URL.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.website.com/call-desired-url');   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 900);
$content = curl_exec($ch);  
curl_close($ch);
```